# angularJS filter "orderBy" fails to sort 3+ digits numbers

Tags: mysql, angularjs, sorting

I'm trying to sort integers in a table from smallest to biggest but 3+ digits number goes to bottom of table.

I get data from a mysql table and sort it in a table using angulars filter "orderBy" like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <td>name</td>
    <td>score</td>
    <td>diff</td>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy: '-score'">
        <td >{{x.name}}</td>
        <td >{{x.score}}</td>
        <td>{{(maxScore(names)-x.score)}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

maxScore(names) simply finds the biggest score value in the names array and returns it:

JS:

```
$scope.maxScore = function(names){
    var max;
    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        if (names[i].score > (max || 0))
            max = names[i].score;
    }
    return max;
}
```

the table has 3 columns (id,name,score) and score field holds integers.

the sorting works perfect for 2 digit numbers  but if the number in names[i].score is 1 or 3+ digits the sorting fails - every number which is 3+ digits goes to the bottom of the table instead of the top. all  the 2 digit numbers are sorted out as expected from big to small.can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: It's probably because you're not actually sorting numbers. They're probably string represented numbers and you need to `parseInt()` them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what specifically is wrong, but [I cleaned up your code in a codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/myWrra?editors=101) and things seem to work.

```
<!-- markup -->
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Score</th>
      <th>Diff</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:'-score'">
      <td>{{player.name}}</td>
      <td>{{player.score}}</td>
      <td>{{maxScore() - player.score}}
    </tr>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

// JS
function ctrl ($scope) {
  $scope.players = [
    // fake data with different digit scores
  ]

  $scope.maxScore = function() {
    var max;
    angular.forEach($scope.players, function(player) {
      if (player.score > (max || 0))
        max = player.score;
    });
    return max;
  }
}
```

Maybe you're not actually dealing with numbers but strings of numbers and you should `parseInt` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
ranks in ranking | orderBy:max:'amount'
```

Try this inside ng-repeat, this will help order data by the max value.

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friends">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone Number</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:'-age'">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[You can always follow the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: Could you show more detail to help explain this for everyone.